# Groovy Map: How to Get key from a value which in an array of strings

Tags: groovy, jira

Hope this question finds you all well.

I have a map like this

```
def maps = 
[
    "hello": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "goodbye": ["4", "5", "6"]
]
```

By referring [Map.Find](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure)), I tried to get the key `hello` by using value in the value array, for example string `"2"`, but it did not return anything.

Here are what i have tried so far

```
def wishKey = maps.find{it.value == "1"}.key

def wishKey = maps.find{it.find{it.value == "1"}}.key

def wishKey = maps.find{it.find{it["1"]}.key

def wishKey = maps.find{it.value.find{it["1"]}.key
```

Is there something that I missed?

Any pointers would be great!

Additional Info: I'm trying to achieve this in **JIRA ScriptRunner** in their **ScriptEditor** using *Behaviour Script*.

While the `maps` are hardcoded because I'm trying to compare the value of a key with a value that I get from a custom field dropdown.
I have confirmed that the custom field dropdown value is `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 1):

Your closures are just a little lost in the way they're searching for values. All of the following should work. The first thing I'd do is explicitly name inner closure parameters (more for readability)

```
maps.find{it.value.find{e -> e == '2'}}.key
maps.find{it.value.find{it == "2"}}.key //also works, but I wouldn't do this
```

You can also use other list methods

```
maps.find{it.value.contains("2")}.key
maps.find{it.value.indexOf("2") >= 0}.key
```

For a summary of what's wrong with the code:

```
def wishKey = maps.find{it.value == "1"}.key //compares list with "1"
def wishKey = maps.find{it.find{it.value == "1"}}.key //calls find on map entry
def wishKey = maps.find{it.find{it["1"]}.key //calls find on map entry
def wishKey = maps.find{it.value.find{it["1"]}.key //it["1"] slices strings
```

Comment: Be aware that all of those are going to throw a NullPointerException if there is no match.  You could deal with that by replacing something like `maps.find{it.value.contains("2")}.key` with `maps.find{it.value.contains("2")}?.key`.

Comment: Hi @ernest_k , appreciate your pointer. Unfortunately, I did not manage to get it to work in the JiRA Script Runner Script Editor. I have updated my question above.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
maps.findResult { 
    if(it.value.contains('2')) { it.key } 
}
```

Or this:

```
maps.findResult { entry ->
    if(entry.value.contains('2')) { entry.key }
}
```

(This code assumes that all of the values are collections and skips any error handling to deal otherwise)

Comment: Hi @Jeff Scott Brown, appreciate your pointer. Unfortunately, I did not manage to get it to work in the JiRA Script Runner Script Editor. I have updated my question above.

Comment: "I did not manage to get it to work in the JiRA Script Runner Script Editor." - I have not been able to reproduce whatever problem you are having.  I am sorry that I cannot help.  Best of luck!